# Is a Waitable Timer a Multimedia Timer?

Tags: winapi, timer

It says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/about-multimedia-timers):

> Multimedia timer services allow applications to schedule timer events with the greatest resolution (or accuracy) possible for the hardware platform. These multimedia timer services allow you to schedule timer events at a higher resolution than other timer services.

But it also says (emphasis mine):

> **Applications that do not use high-resolution timing should use the SetTimer function instead** of multimedia timer services. The timer services provided by SetTimer post WM_TIMER messages to a message queue, while the multimedia timer services call a callback function. **Applications that want a waitable timer should use the CreateWaitableTimer function.**

I'm finding that this code:

```c
timer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, TRUE, NULL);
SetWaitableTimer(timer, &due, 0, NULL, NULL, 0);
WaitForSingleObject(timer, INFINITE);
CloseHandle(timer);
```

results in rather imprecise (+/- 1 millisecond) waiting. With `QueryPerformanceCounter()` and busy waiting I can easily achieve microsecond accuracy.

So does that mean that `CreateWaitableTimer()` is *not* a "Multimedia Timer" and thus does not "allow me to schedule timer events with the greatest resolution"?

Is there a similar API that I can use to wait more precisely without eating a whole CPU core?

Comment: here task not in Timer but in wait (`WaitForSingleObject` in your case). the thread sheduler is *imprecise* - Timer can be set in signal state precise, but this not mean that your thread just exit from wait state. +/- 1 millisecond this is normal.

Comment: Given that the maximum timer resolution [you can request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod) is 1ms, you won't get sub-millisecond precision even when using multimedia timers. What's the specific problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable Since it's possible to *measure* with nanosecond resolution I somehow assumed it must also be possible to *wait* with that resolution, as long as the system is idle. I realize now that that might have been a baseless assumption. The actual "problem" was that I was writing a unit test for some instrumentation code and I used the above code to sleep and then asserted that the elapsed time was more or less the given amount. I got vastly different results, so I investigated.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your **title** question:

Following the (admittedly rather obscure) navigation trail from the post you linked, it would appear that the API routine you should be using to create/use such a "multimedia timer" is [`CreateTimerQueueTimer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoollegacyapiset/nf-threadpoollegacyapiset-createtimerqueuetimer). This will schedule one or more callbacks at the specified time/period, without requiring any explicit "wait" code/calls, and will (presumably) offer the best (~1 ms) resolution/accuracy for your timed events.

This (to me, at least) implies that this `CreateTimerQueueTimer()` function creates what your linked page refers to as a "multimedia timer", due to the phrase (that you quote): *"while the multimedia timer services call a callback function"*. The "waitable timer" returned from a `CreateWaitableTimer()` call would *only* satisfy that requirement of using a callback *if* you specify a valid function as the 4<sup>th</sup> argument of the following `SetWaitableTimer()` call (which your short example code does *not* do).

---

To address your second point: *Is there a similar API that I can use to wait more precisely without eating a whole CPU core?*

Not that I'm aware of. When using the QPC functions and clocks ("polling"), there will always be a trade-off between CPU usage and wait precision; that's just the way things work.

You could *maybe* consider using an off-board timer chip that can generate hardware interrupts (it's what I do for software that needs to control equipment with sub-millisecond precision) – but that may be beyond your remit.